# How to force `img` tag to respect parent `picture` parameters?

Tags: css, image, attributes, width

Is there any way, that `img` element (set to `width:100%`) was following parent `<picture>` element's `width` **attribute**? Here is an example to demonstrate, that it only follows "style" property, and not attribute:

```html
First:
<picture width="15" style="display:inline-block;">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FqUFgYd.png" style="width: 100%;">
</picture>

Second:
<picture width="15" style="display:inline-block; width:15px;">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FqUFgYd.png" style="width: 100%;">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `<picture>` element [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) only [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), so `width="15"` isn't supported by the `<picture>` element. It can be done only by defining `<picture>` element in **CSS**, adding **ID/class** or by adding `**style=""**` into element.

```html
Second:
<picture style="display:inline-block; width:15px;">
     <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FqUFgYd.png" style="width: 100%;">
</picture>
```